# MySql select sum and calculate percentage per column

Tags: mysql

Following a select, where I get sums grouped by ids, I need to calculate also the percentage of each sum with respect to the totals

The MySQL table looks like the following

```
|status|a|b1|b2|c1|c2|
-------------------------
|IMMA  |1|0 |0 |1 |0 |
|IMMA  |0|1 |1 |0 |1 |
|IMMA  |1|1 |1 |0 |1 |
|IMMA  |1|1 |1 |0 |1 |
```

The query I use now is

```
SELECT imma_dbase_full.`status`,
SUM(imma_dbase_full.`a`) as `A`,
SUM(imma_dbase_full.`b1`) + SUM(imma_dbase_full.`b2`) as `B`,
SUM(imma_dbase_full.`c1`) + SUM(imma_dbase_full.`c2`) as `C`
FROM imma_dbase_full
WHERE imma_dbase_full.`status` = 'IMMA'
GROUP BY imma_dbase_full.`status`;
```

The output is

```
|status|A|B|C|
----------------
|IMMA  |3|6|3|
```

However I need to create an output as the following:

```
|status|A  |B  |C  |
-------------------- 
|IMMA  |3  |6  |3  |
|%     |25%|50%|25%|
```

Is that possible with MySQL?

Comment: Seems a bit odd. Why don't you perform the required logic for % in the application part/or report if it's for a report? Is it essential for it to look like that ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do the calculation in a separate SELECT then UNION the two, making it appears as one, but it's not a very good solution. For optimization, it would be better to calculate the percentage at application level.

```
SELECT `status`,
SUM(`a`) as `A`,
SUM(`b1`+`b2`) as `B`,
SUM(`c1`+`c2`) as `C`
FROM imma_dbase_full
WHERE `status` = 'IMMA'
UNION
SELECT '%',
SUM(`a`) / SUM(`a`+`b1`+`b2`+`c1`+`c2`) * 100,
SUM(`b1`+`b2`) / SUM(`a`+`b1`+`b2`+`c1`+`c2`) * 100,
SUM(`c1`+`c2`) / SUM(`a`+`b1`+`b2`+`c1`+`c2`) * 100
FROM imma_dbase_full
WHERE `status` = 'IMMA'
```

Ps.: In your original query the `GROUP BY` makes no sense, since you're filtering on `Status=IMMA` so there will be only one status, there is no need to group by.

Comment: Thanks I will try your solution. The problems are: 1) I’m a beginner in MySQL (this explains also the redundant group by) 2) the query is used by WpDataTables and I don’t see a way to make the plugin calculating that percentage

Comment: Just for the records the query works fine and it is the best solution for me now. As I was using the query with WP DataTables, I realized that the UNION instruction is not accepted in the plugin, hence I created a VIEW in Mysql and called the view directly.